# How to keep word width after hover (font changes from light to bold on hover)?

Tags: html, css, fonts, hover

I've got some words like WORD and REALLYLONGWORD. Both have light font and I want them to become bold on mouse over. Both have `float: left; width: auto;`. I can't give them fixed width.

The problem is when I hover WORD, the REALLYLONGWORD jumps to the right because WORD gets bolder font (and larger width value). Is there any CSS-only workaround to that?

EDIT (I can't answer my own question, so I'm posting answer below):
I found some CSS-only solution. HTML:

```
<div class="thtitled-thtitle"><div class="thtitles-title">WORD</div><div class="thtitles-titlebold">WORD</div></div>
<div class="thtitled-thtitle"><div class="thtitles-title">REALLYLONGWORD</div><div class="thtitles-titlebold">REALLYLONGWORD</div></div>
```

CSS:

```
.thtitled-thtitle { float: left; }
.thtitles-titlebold { visibility: hidden; color: #F5F5F5; cursor: pointer; float: left; font-family: 'BOLDFONT',Arial,sans-serif; font-size: 72px; line-height: 96px; min-height: 100px; text-transform: uppercase; width: auto; word-wrap: break-word; } 
.thtitles-title { color: #F5F5F5; cursor: pointer; font-family: 'LIGHTFONT',Arial,sans-serif; font-size: 72px; line-height: 96px; min-height: 100px; text-transform: uppercase; width: auto; word-wrap: break-word; position: absolute; } 
.thtitles-title:hover { font-family: 'BOLDFONT',Arial,sans-serif; }
```

Basically, I create one more hidden container with BOLD font (its width is main width) and put LIGHT font inside. After hover it still has width of BOLD word so there is no jumping.

Comment: More code than provided above is redundant here. I'm asking about general idea. Answers below are good ideas and I'll test them in a minute.

Answer (score 0):

Use letter spacing. For example `{letter-spacing:0.04em}`

If you style your WORD with enough letter spacing to make it the same overall width as the same word when it is bold, and remove the letter spacing when it is bold, everything else will stay put.

It works - try this (this just demos the concept - not what I'm recommending for production):

```
<b>Rotterdam</b><br>
<span style="letter-spacing:0.04em">Rotterdam</span><br/>
<b>and</b><br>
<span style="letter-spacing:0.04em">and</span><br/>
<b>Oslo</b><br>
<span style="letter-spacing:0.04em">Oslo</span><br/>
<b>letter</b><br>
<span style="letter-spacing:0.04em">letter</span><br/>
```

Comment: But can you know how much space to add to it exactly that will make it become the same width as the bold font?

Comment: This works but only for short OR long words. If it works for short words (with letter-spacing: -1px;) then it doesn't work for long words (they require letter-spacing: -2px;)

Comment: You have to experiment. For a given font, you can work out what letter spacing gives best results. For example, I find that 0.04em works best for default serif font (Times-Roman).

Answer (score 0):

You do not want to add any width to fonts at all, I suggest you delete the width property competely. (I also hope you noticed the writing error in your css, with should be width)

The next thing is assign a class to the the ahref this can be easily done with SPAN tags

once done in the css just do:
    .firstlinkclass{
    font-weight: bold; 
    }

Comment: When width is not set it becomes width of the word and it obviously increases after change from light to bold. That's default version I have right now. I'm looking for some solution to set width to like `width: auto + 30px;`

Answer (score 0):

I know this was asked a long long time ago, but I just came up with a solution to fix the jump that works well so I thought I'd share.

Instead of making the font bold on hover, make it have a text-shadow. No jump, same effect, one line of CSS.